# jqMobi - Scroller div inside Carousel?

Tags: overflow, mobile-website, jqmobi

So, I'm putting together the framework for a web app that allows people to swipe horizontally between views. I'm looking for a layout similar to that of ubersocial, an app for android. I've tried a few different frameworks over the last couple of days (including the beginnings of a custom framework, which won't work due to poor overflow:auto support on mobile). JqMobi seems to get me closest.

Here's some code:

```
<script>
    //jqMobi & jqUI scripts omitted for brevity
    var carousel;
    var scroller;
    function init_carousel ()
    {
        carousel = $("#carousel").carousel({
            preventDefaults: false
        });

        scroller = $('newContainer').scroller();
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", init_carousel, false);
</script>

<div id="jQUi">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <!--scrolling="no" because I don't want the whole carousel to move-->
        <div title="Main" id="main" class="panel" data-tab="navbar_home" scrolling="no">
            <div id="carousel" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
            <div id="View1" class="MainView" style="background: yellow;">
                    <div id="newContainer" style="width: 100%;height: 100%; overflow: auto;>
                        <!--Lots of Content-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="View2" class="MainView" style="background: green;"></div>
                <div id="View3" class="MainView" style="background: blue;"></div>
                <div id="View4" class="MainView" style="background: pink;"></div>
                <div id="View5" class="MainView" style="background: orange;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I've got my carousel working for all devices and I was able to get perfect functionality in iOS 5. However, Android (2.2, 2.3, & 4.0) is not giving me a scrollable div for my .MainView elements, nor are older iOS devices. The best I can get is the carousel on a panel that scrolls, but the elements within the panel won't scroll together. This makes me wonder if the iOS 5 success I've had was just support for overflow:auto.

Anyway, I've looked at the following docs:

- jqMobi CheatSheet = (http://www.appmobi.com/amdocs/lib/jqMobi_Cheat.pdf?r=9170)
- jqMobi Kitchen Sink = (http://jqmobi.com/testdrive/#webslider)
- jqMobi API Doc = (http://api.jqmobi.com/#jqUi)

But I've had trouble really getting the answer I'm looking for. Using the documented methods, I can't really seem to get anywhere. It seems like if I could get an independently scrollable div into a .MainView element without breaking the carousel, I'd be good to go. Suggestions?

/********************************FIXED********************************/

After a tangled web of confusion and frustration, I eventually got it to work by adding a second buffer to the .MainDiv elements so that the scroller doesn't affect the carousel.

I also had a bad run-in with iOS 5 (which, as you may recall, worked before) which probably could have been fixed by simply adding overflow:auto to the .MainView elements and giving them a fixed height. I tried disabling nativeTouchScroll first, and the scrolling is actually pretty good, so I'll stick with that instead of adding a browser detect conditional.

```
<script>
//Native touch disabled or iOS 5 breaks.
$.feat.nativeTouchScroll = false;

var carousel;
//var scroller;
function init_carousel ()
{
    carousel = $("#carousel").carousel({
        preventDefaults: false
    });
}

$.ui.ready(init_carousel);

var scroller;
$.ui.ready(function ()
{
    //Fetch the scroller from cache
    scroller = $("#containerContainer").scroller();
});
</script>


<style>
.MainView
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>


<div id="carousel" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    <div id="View1" class="MainView" style="background: yellow;">
        <div id="containerContainer"><div id="newContainer"></div></div>
        </div>
    <div id="View2" class="MainView" style="background: green;"></div>
    <div id="View3" class="MainView" style="background: blue;"></div>
    <div id="View4" class="MainView" style="background: pink;"></div>
    <div id="View5" class="MainView" style="background: orange;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posted in the forums at appMobi - but we are a US based company in the Eastern Standard Time Zone - so we were asleep while you were working on this...glad you wrote the following :)

> Not that anyone seems to care

Comment: That's a fair point. I didn't intend to criticize appMobi (or anyone else for that matter). The "Not that anyone seems to care" was my own twisted jest (laced with long-term frustration and sleep deprivation). I'll go ahead and remove it to make this more useful if anyone else runs across it.